# Iterate on figures in plotly to create an animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

My function to create figures looks as follows:

```
def bar_plot_plotly(self, frame=None):

md = self.get_book()

plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
fig = go.Figure()
if md:
    for step in range(2):
        fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
            mode = "number+gauge+delta", value = md.qasks[step],
            delta = {'reference':  md.qasks[step]},
            domain = {'x': [0, 0.4], 'y': [0.2*step, 0.2*step+0.1]},
            title = {'text': str(md.asks[step])},
            gauge = {
                'shape': "bullet",
                'axis': {'range': [min(md.qasks), max(md.qasks)]},
                'threshold': {
                'line': {'color': "red", 'width': 2},
                'thickness': 0.75,
                'value': md.qasks[step]},
                'bar': {'color': "red"}}))

        fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
            mode = "number+gauge+delta", value = md.qbids[step],
            delta = {'reference': md.qbids[step]},
            domain = {'x': [0.6, 1], 'y': [0.2*step, 0.2*step+0.1]},
            title = {'text': str(md.bids[step])},
            gauge = {
                'shape': "bullet",
                'axis': {'range': [min(md.qbids), max(md.qbids)]},
                'threshold': {
                'line': {'color': "green", 'width': 2},
                'thickness': 0.75,
                'value': md.qbids[step]},
                'bar': {'color': "green"}}))
```

So at each iteration, it creates a figure, my goal would be to iterate on each of those figures in order to create an animation. The idea would be to do the same as in the documentation `https://plot.ly/python/animations/#animated-bar-charts-with-plotly-express`, but in there they use a pandas DataFrame, I would like to do it per figure basically. 
I used to use `Funcanimation` on matplotlib, I was thus wondering if it was possible to use the above code to do the same? Any advice is more than welcome! 
Thanks